# Blueimp FileUpload : How to submit the upload after submitting form callback

Tags: jquery, blueimp

I've got a *"new product"* form with several inputs (name, description, etc) and a "add image" button (that just loads the preview image when you click on it).

Once I submit the *"new product"* form (image is not uploaded at this time), if the MySQL query is OK, it returns me the **last inserted ID**. Then, I want to submit the upload of the image with the variable of the **last inserted ID** (used to generate the name of the file, ie : 123465.jpg) I got when I first submitted the "new product" form. Does it make sense?

So, I need to **submit** the image upload form, outside of this code :

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + '/files/index.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data) {
            var uploadErrors = [];
            var acceptFileTypes = /^image\/(jpe?g|png)|application\/(pdf|doc|xls|vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet)$/i;
            if(data.originalFiles[0]['type'].length && !acceptFileTypes.test(data.originalFiles[0]['type'])) {
                uploadErrors.push("Bad file : " + '\n\n' + data.originalFiles[0]['name'] + '\n\n' + "Accepted : " + '\n' + "jpg, png, pdf, doc, xls, xlsx ou zip.");
            }
            if(data.originalFiles[0]['size'].length && data.originalFiles[0]['size'] > 5000000) {
                uploadErrors.push("Too heavy : " + '\n\n' + data.originalFiles[0]['name']);
            }
            if(uploadErrors.length > 0) {
                alert(uploadErrors.join("\n"));
            } else {
                $('#preview').html('<img src="' + URL.createObjectURL(data.files[0]) + '"/>');
            }
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            console.log(progress);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
$('.fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'image_upload/server/php/index.php',
    maxFileSize: 5000 * 1000,
    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
}).on('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {    
    alert("submit triggered");
    //Code which needs to comes after submit
});
```